# BlackBerry Calendar or Date .roll(), .add()?

Tags: date, blackberry, time, calendar

I am working on a BlackBerry application and I need a way to find out the millis value of tomorrow morning at 1am. On Android, this would a job for Calendar.add(), or Calendar.roll(). But the Calendar class in BlackBerry doesn't seem to have either of these methods. Is my only option to do the arithmetic on millis values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at DateTimeUtilities, specifically `getNextDate()`. I think that you can probably get it to do what you need with that.

http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html